# Slower boot speed after problematic RAM upgrade / DRAM LED stays longer

Tags: memory, upgrade, burning, dram

I've updated my 8GB RAM to 12 GB and now I have a slower boot time plus long DRAM LED light duration (apx 5 seconds.) when turning on the device which makes the boot time even longer. I'd appreciate if you can help me with this.

Here is my background story:
I had 4 x 2GB = 8GB of ram before (kvr1333d3n9/2g). Then I bought 2x 4GB RAM (same 1333Mhz, same brand, same series kvr1333d3n9/4g ). I replaced 2x2GB RAM with 2x4GB RAM so in total I had 12 GB ram. There the problem started. I believe I did not fit one of the rams to its slot properly because I had no screen when I first turned on the device. Worse than this, I had a burning smell then I immediately turned off the device & switched the power button off at the back of the case. I put my nose everywhere and did not get the exact smell source. Meanwhile, I was googling what could make my screen off when booting.

I realized that I did not push one side of a RAM. Then pushed harder and felt that it finally fit into mobo completely. (My mobo has single RAM clippers). After this step I turned on the PC again being afraid of causing a bigger problem. But no! The system booted just like before. The only difference I have now is my longer boot time & seeing DRAM Red light for like 5 seconds when I turn on the device.

Some useful info for you:
MOBO: ASUS P7H55D-M EVO (Bios is updated)
GPU: GTX 1060 3GB
CPU: Xeon 3470
RAM: 12 GB 1333mhz  (CPUz shows 12GB ram with dual-channel)

Did memtest all is ok with 0 error. 
Played high-end graphics game to push the PC to its limits to see if anything happens. Nothing happened.

I checked my mobo and did not see any trace of burnings. Something definitely happened because of this serious burning smell. I feel anxious now..

Thought seeking your help would be better.

---

update:

I realized that my system is using 6GB of RAM now even though CPU-Z shows that I have 12 GB of RAM!

At first Windows Resource Monitor showed my total ram as 12 GB / 6GB Hardware Reserved. Then I made a change in registry editor. Now it shows my total ram as 6GB even though I changed the value back to its original number 0.

Adding related screenshots below:
https://ibb.co/SB6Wkf0
https://ibb.co/jJN3vqB
https://ibb.co/nrNZvtS

---

last update:

I opened the case and switched ram sticks' place. Put 2x2GB A1-B1 and 2x4GB A2-B2. Now PC booted with normal speed. System recognizes 12GB RAM. No prob.

Still curios about what that burning smell was..

Comment: burning smell == **you let the magic smoke out**. There is no putting it back in. You need a service engineer.

Comment: Disable/Enable Secure Boot for ASUS Motherboard

Comment: Yea, if you smelled smoke there are damaged components in the system and you need a qualified technician to physically inspect the system

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because due to the smell of smoke the computer has sustained hardware damage and needs to be inspected in person by a qualified technician.